# Should I use Java modularity into my existing Maven multi module web project when migrating to Java9+?

Tags: java, maven, java-module

I have an existing **Multi modules maven project** (in Java 8), one of thoses modules is a webapp which produce a **war file** deployed into **Tomcat 9**.

I planned to migrate to **Java 11**. I am wondering if there is a **benefit** of adding **java modularity** to my project (i.e. creating a `module-info.java` for each maven modules) ?

Is there any **benefit** of adding Java Modularity when producing a war file (maven will already add all its dependencies in WEB-INF/lib) ?

At final, I suppose Tomcat is not using Java modularity when deploying the war ? So, I can't see any benefit of using Java modularity in a **web environment**, maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: See more details https://stackoverflow.com/q/46497172/296328 apart from that currently I don't see any reason to use java modularity for a resulting WAR file...

Comment: yes I saw this post, but the answer was posted in 2017. So even in 2019, java modularity is not ready for webapp environment ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on whether or not you are experiencing problems that modulization was intended to fix.  I work in a Spring microservices team.  We did not start using modules when we migrated to Java 10 from 8.  Mainly because we were not encountering the problems that modules was intended to fix... like conflicting library dependencies, or large packages.  So no need for the extra complexity.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I am not planning to use it, everything works perfectly fine without modularity. I also see that Spring initializr is not adding module-info.java when creating a java 11 spring project...